# Why do not I need to import java.lang when using Runtime?

Tags: java

In the piece of code below, Why do I need to import `java.awt.Robot` but I can use `Runtime` without importing `java.lang.Runtime`?

```
package classes;

import java.awt.Robot;

public class RuntimeExecution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad");
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(65);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Answers below are correct, but why is java.lang automatically imported for you?  It's because classes in that package are essential for any JVM or essential for the language itself.  Even the simplest Java class file references several of the java.lang classes (e.g., `Object`, `Class`, `String`), about half of them are necessary to implement basic language features (e.g., `Throwable`, `Iterable`, and all of the boxed types), and most of the rest of java.lang will be used by any practical JVM when it loads and runs any program (`Thread`, `ClassLoader`, `System`, `Runtime`, ...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For convenience, the Java compiler automatically imports two entire packages for each source file:

1. The java.lang package and
2. The current package (the package
   for the current file).

[Please ref. oracle.com for more info (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)

Answer (score 8):

[Because](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.3)

> Every compilation unit implicitly imports every public type name
> declared in the predefined package `java.lang`, as if the declaration
> `import java.lang.*;` appeared at the beginning of each compilation unit
> immediately after any package statement. **As a result, the names of all
> those types are available as simple names in every compilation unit.**

where a *compilation unit* is basically your `.java` source file.